# Can not delete files containing special characters in the file name

Tags: command-line, special-characters

I use Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic) and I have a directory with many files, among them these two files:

```
./baer.jpg
./bär.jpg
```

I would like to delete `bär.jpg` but I can't.

If I type `rm b` and hit `TAB`, it shows me both files, if I append `ä` and hit `TAB`, nothing gets displayed.

What must be done in order to delete `bär.jpg`?

Deleting the parent folder is not a solution for me, as there are plenty of files in this directory that are used by a productive environment.

Comment: Try using midnight commander. I think you can install it with `sudo apt get install mc`. After that, run it with `mc` and us it to delete your file.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a command-line solution.

Comment: I thought so, that's why I put this in comments :)

Comment: Techmically you could rename baer.jpg, remove bar.jpg and rename baer.jpg back ;-)

Comment: midnight commander _is_ command line. Do you mean coreutils?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just found out how to delete such files witch special characters:

1. `cd <directory with that file>`
2. `ls -ali`
3. At the very left of the directory listing you see the ID of the inode of each file.
4. Delete your file via inode ID:

   `find . -inum <inode ID of your file> -exec rm -i {} \;`

This worked fine for my issue. Hope this helps!

Comment: +1. Very nice, if a bit convoluted. Note that `-execdir` is preferred (see `man find`). Also, another alternative would be to just run it with `-delete` instead, although this doesn't give you the warning of the `-i` flag.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [bash wildcards](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) with

```
 rm b?r.jpg
```

where `?` stands for exactly one character. An alternative (if both file names were the same length) would be

```
rm b[!e]r.jpg
```

where `[!e]` means any character except "e".

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try using matching via `grep` to delete the file if it's a single problematic file.

```
neal@dsadsa:~$ touch junk_ä_deleteme
neal@dsadsa:~$ ls | grep junk | grep deleteme | xargs rm
```

Here, I am creating a file named `junk_ä_deleteme`. I delete it afterward by matching characters before ("junk") and after ("deleteme") the funny symbol. This approach isn't very good, but if it is a single file, it might work.

Perhaps a better solution would be to form a regex to match your file, and then pipe that filename to `rm`.

Comment: Piping `ls` to `grep` can be unintuitive. Probably easier to just use something like `find . -name 'junk*deleteme' -delete`