# Can't delete a file with a '?' in the file name

Tags: delete, rm

Can't delete a file with a '?' in the file name, it fails to delete with the message 'the file does not exist'.

I've tried through the terminal using

```
rm -f ./pathtofile\?.mkv
```

But despite no failure message the file still exists. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just now got 50 points so converting to comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/233158/can-not-delete-files-containing-special-characters-in-the-file-name

Comment: @AndroidDev To flag a post as a duplicate, you can use the "flag" link under the question: you'll be prompted for the link of the duplicate question and a system will post a comment in your behalf automatically.

Comment: @AndroidDev No problem. You may still flag the question if you think it's a duplicate. I suggest you have a read here so that you can get an idea of how flagging works exactly: http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/flag-posts.

Comment: Just so you know, the `-f` flag tells it to suppress error messages in case of failure, and fail silently.  So it's a good idea not to use that flag if you want more information about why something failed.

Comment: This does appear to be a duplicate @android-dev, I was being too narrow with my search when I tried to find a solution for this. Thanks for the note about `-f` @thomasrutter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `?` is most likely another non-ASCII symbol that your terminal program is unable to display so it displays `?`. This is easily proven - you can execute `touch ?.mkv` and `rm ?.mkv` - both command execute just fine.

Files like that are easily deleted using a GUI file manager.

Alternatively you could try using wildcards. If command:

```
ls pathtofile\FewLetters*.mkv
```

lists a single file you can safely run:

```
rm pathtofile\FewLetters*.mkv`.
```

Finally you could try the harder but surer way as described in [Can not delete files containing special characters in the file name](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233158/can-not-delete-files-containing-special-characters-in-the-file-name) as pointed by Android Dev above.

Comment: Duh, how did I not think of that, Obvious really! Thanks, this worked for my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Does the file really have a `?` in the filename, or is it a non-printing character that `ls` shows as a `?`?

```
$ touch $'a\ab' 'a?b'
$ ls
a?b  a?b
```

One file has an ASCII BELL character in the name, and the other has a plain old question mark.

Newer versions of `ls` can show it special characters in a clearer form by default:

```
$ touch $'b\aa'
$ ls
'b'$'\a''a'
```

`ls -q` is how older versions of `ls` show non-printing characters by default. So, if you just do `ls` in any current version of Ubuntu, you're likely to see just question marks.

Try, instead, one of:

```
$ ls -b
a?b  a\ab
$ printf "%q\n" *
a\?b
$'a\ab'
```

If the output from either of these don't have question marks, then the filename doesn't have question marks.

You can use the output of `printf` for deleting:

```
rm a\?b
rm $'a\ab'
```

Or rely on tab completion:

```
$ rm a<tab>
a?b   a^Gb
```

If it shows `^G`, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to enter it. Or tell [bash to cycle through tab completions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24421/70524):

```
$ bind tab:menu-complete
$ rm a<tab>
$ rm a\?b<tab>
$ rm a^Gb
```

In either case, using `rm a?b` *could* work, but is dangerous. It would match *all* filenames starting with `a`, ending in `b` and having one character in between:

```
$ touch acb; printf "%q\n" a?b
a\?b
$'a\ab'
acb
```

So, if you do `rm a?b` (or worse, `rm a*b`), you could end up deleting files you didn't intend to.

Comment: I did not try this as I just wanted the file gone and the other answers worked for me. But you covered some stuff I didn't know, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

`rm -f 'path?.mkv'` works for me. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the `' '` does disable the functionality of some special characters such as `?` . Sorry for the bad formatting, rplying in speed gotta hurry.
Hope it helps, have a nice day =)

Comment: This worked, after I posted I found another file and this did not work for that. But good to know thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just do an ls -i which shows the inode.

Than do rm $(find . -inum inodeoffile)