# Error accessing a file no such file or directory (I want to rename it)

Tags: files, filesystem, ls, mv

I am struggling to rename a file, I had a [similar issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/746048/cant-delete-a-file-with-a-in-the-file-name) sometime ago but in that case I wanted to delete, this time I simply want to access it.

I have cleared the directory, so only this single file remains, making wildcards easier to use.

```
ls -la
ls: 'My.Name.is.Earl.S01E12(O.Karma,Where.Art.Thou?).mp4': No such file or directory
total 204816
drwxrwxrwx+ 2 noki noki         0 Jul  2  2018  .
drwxrwxrwx+ 7 noki noki         0 Jul  2  2018  ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 noki noki 209711256 Jan 18  2015 'My.Name.is.Earl.S01E12(O.Karma,Where.Art.Thou?).mp4'
```

If I use wildcards to rename it I get the same error about the file not existing.

Since LS says the file doesn't exist then proceeds to give me stats for it is strange. I simply want to rename it so I can access it again, what can I try?

Comment: Filesystem corruption, likely. Run `fsck` on it.

Comment: Unfortunately I neglected to mention it was a file on my NAS. So will be more complex. Will look into how to do this on their directly since I obviously can't unmount it and still do this. Thanks for your help.